# Calculating wts in gammatone-gram

Tags: audio

I am working on speech segmentation using gammatone filters.

I can't understand the variable named `GTord` to calculate wts(weight) in the `fft2gammatonemx.mat` file.

This code can be downloaded form the following [link](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/resources/matlab/gammatonegram/).

Comment: you can use a link as a reference, however dont expect anyone to click on it. You should post the code here and explain in more detail why you are having problems to understand / follow the idea of the code. Just saying "I dont understand it, solve it for me" wont encourage anyone to help you

Comment: Here is the code. I can't understand the variable named "GTord"  at line number 131.I want to understand GTord means in gammatone like spectrogram's background theory.

Comment: Sorry,code is too long for permitted characters.

Comment: You dont have to post the entire code but rather only the part which confuses you. But dont post the code alone, explain what you would expect and what is different and why this confuses you. You need to put effort in the problem you are having. Just asking for help with no investigations from your side wont bring you anywhere.